# How can I make $row to real link

Tags: php

I have `$row["vLink"]` `vlink(varchar(200))` is a URL address I got from MySQL. But when I'm printing vLink looks in text form not a real link. How can make a clickable IMG link with using vLink?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["vLink"];
}
```

Comment: `echo '<a href="'.$row["vLink"].'">Click Here</a>';`

Comment: You need to put your link into html tag. Something like this `echo sprintf("<a href='%s'>This is a link</a>", $row["vLink"])` for the link or `echo sprintf("<img src='%s'>", $row["vLink"])` for the image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473731/4248328

Comment: @alexey-novikov it says " Parameter is not mapped to any conversion specification " for $row["vLink"] . I see img but link is not working.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Im asking for link img not for only link.  It not ` similar question` I think :)

Comment: you can do the same Just add `<img src="'.image src variable.'"`>` in place of `click here`. ex: `<a href="'.$row["vLink"].'"><img src="'.<put image src variable here>.'"`></a>`

Comment: @AlivetoDie sir Im sorry but  `echo '<a href="'.$row["vLink"].'"><img src="'.<default.jpg>.'"></a>'` is not working

Comment: @serdaraksoy is not working isnt a proper answer , add more details to your comments / questions .

Comment: @serdaraksoy it needs to be: echo `'<a href="'.$row["vLink"].'"><img src="default.jpg"></a>'`. Also you need to provide path of `default.jpg` inside `img src`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL and link text from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473594/url-and-link-text-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make clickable image

```
echo '<a href="'.$row["vLink"].'">'.' <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket"> '.'</a>';
```

When you will click on image it will re-direct you to that `link`( $row["vLink"] )

Answer (score 0):

Put Your Link in anchor tag to make it a clickable link

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$row["vLink"].'">'.$row["vLink"].'</a>';            
  }?>
```

Comment: actually Im asking for clickable  img link